# Meaning and solution for Spring 3 error message? "Using getResponseBodyAsStream instead is recommended"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3 and every time I submit a HTML form to a Spring controller I get this message, which I don't understand:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase getResponseBody
WARNING: Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size. 
Using getResponseBodyAsStream instead is recommended.
```

Is there a configuration change I can make in Spring to avoid this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This occurs with the commons-httpclient API when the getResponseBody() method is used.  The warning means that a response body could potentially be very large (such as a large file download, etc.) and loading the whole thing into memory at once as a String could be very inefficient.  The way to avoid this potential inefficiency is to use getResponseBodyAsStream(), which will allow proper buffering and streaming of the response body.

I am not sure why Spring is using getResponseBody().  Could it be your HTTP client?  Are you using a custom-written HTTP client to perform the request?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a custom-written HTTP client". I'm using Spring/Jetty on the server side and Firefox on the client side.

Comment: I thought you might be using your own HTTP client in a unit test, for example.  Since you're using Firefox the warning is likely triggered by Spring's use of getResponseBody().  If that's the case, I wouldn't worry too much about it.  You can change your log4j configuration to suppress the warning if it bothers you, but it's not likely a cause for alarm.

Answer (score 2):

You can add configuration `http.method.response.buffer.warnlimit=1024*1024*10` in the application.properties. it works for me.